# How many combinations are there

Tags: combinatorics

Given I have $N$ fields. I want to produce $X$ possible matches with a variable $M$ for how many of the fields do not have to equal.

e.g values and results.

$N = 4$
$M = 1$
$X = 5$ (height of the matrix with $N$ as the length)

Considering this could be represented as a matrix with zero representing a non-required match and $1$ representing a match:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1&1&1&1\\
    0&1&1&1\\
    1&0&1&1\\
    1&1&0&1\\
    1&1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Another example:

$N = 4$
$M = 2$
$X =\;?$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1&1&1&1\\
    0&1&1&1\\
    1&0&1&1\\
    1&1&0&1\\
    1&1&1&0\\
    0&0&1&1\\
    0&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
What is the function for X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase the question.

> Given a string $a$ of length $N$, how many strings $b$ are there such that $a$ and $b$ differ by (at maximum) $M$ characters?

(The numeric answer to the question above is your $X$.)

Note that there is $1$ way for the strings to differ by zero characters.  There are $N$ ways for the strings to differ by $1$ character.  There are $\binom{N}{2}$ ways for the strings to differ by $2$ characters.  In general:

$$X = \sum_{k=0}^M\binom{N}{k}$$

**In response to comment:**

We define the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) to be:
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Thus, our expression above becomes:
$$X = \sum_{k=0}^M\binom{N}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^M\frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!}$$

Where $a!$ is the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of $a$.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten most of my maths. How would I add these up? Is there a function which can be represented?

Comment: @Steven Does that help?  I don't think I could give an adequate explanation of summation notation in the answer, so I'll just have to link to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation)

Comment: That's great. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Steven My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just got tired in your last example and didn't do the rest of the lines with two zeros, you've got all the ways to choose no zeroes, one zero, two zeroes.... $$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{k}.$$  There's probably a closed form for that, but I'll leave it for you to work out if you want.

Comment: You beat me! `:)` $(+1)$